# How to choose dialogue options via keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, genshin-impact

When in a dialogue in Genshin Impact, one can either press mouse buttons or press `F` to proceed the text.

But when it comes to a dialogue option where you got one or more options to choose from, is there any key to choose an option?
[image: picture of a dialogue option]

Comment: @Downvoter why the downvotes? Please add a comment to tell what made you vote it down so I may do it better next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no. Tested this myself by hitting every key on my keyboard during a dialog with choices.

Comment: I tested it as well (before I asked) by pressing every key and looking up preferences, but found no key either. Unfortunately. But upon further looking, many actions arent mapped to keys.

Answer (score 3):

I was annoyed by this problem so much that I made a program specifically for this - to be able to scroll and select dialog options with anything (by using mouse wheel and keyboard). It's called Aurora Dialog Enhancer.

Hopefully someone will actually find this useful besides me, because it's just become many times more convenient to play GI.

You can check it on GitHub:
https://github.com/DigitalE4rth/AuroraDialogEnhancer

Comment: Very nifty! +1!